# Alliens ship goes behind scene

Tags: python, pygame

let us suppose we have following  object in game
[image]

i want to  move this object left-right and up and down , so that it should not go out of  scene, corresponding code is here :

```
import sys

import pygame  # contains functionality to make a game

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

# from alien import Alien
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialise the game and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()  # initialise the background settings
        # which the game needs to work properly
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        # creates display window with these dimensions
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        # self.alien = Alien(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self.check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self.update_screen()

    def check_events(self):
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    # Move ship 1 to the right.
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_UP:
                    self.ship.moving_up =True
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.ship.moving_below =True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_UP:
                    self.ship.moving_up =False
                elif event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.ship.moving_below =False


    def update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screenand flip to the new screen."""
        # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        # self.alien.blitme()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # make a game instance and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

setting parameters  are these :

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialise the games settings."""
        self.screen_width = 1000
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        # Ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 0.7
```

and corresponding ship  class is  here :

```
import pygame

from settings import Settings

# x = 1000
# y = 600
class Ship:
    # global x,y
    """A class to manage the ship."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialise the ship and its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("alliens_ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midtop = self.screen_rect.midtop
        # Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_below =False
        self.moving_up =False

    def update(self):
        """Update ships position based on movement flags."""
        # Update the ships x value not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left >= 0:
            self.rect.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if  self.moving_below and self.rect.y <600:
            self.rect.y +=self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.y >0:
            self.rect.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
            if self.rect.y>=600:
                self.rect.y =600
        # Update rect object from self.x
        # self.rect.x = self.x
    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

for left and   right side it works pretty fine, also up  it works fine, but below there is not stopping criteria, i have added following line :

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.y >0:
        self.rect.y -= self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.rect.y>=600:
            self.rect.y =600
```

but it continues  movement, how can i stop it? thanks in advance

Comment: i did not get answer from the  links above, exactly how should i do it?

Comment: 1. Don't need to recommend to us how to answer/comment, we know how to use StackOverflow. 2. In your last code snippet you check `if self.rect.y>=600:` while `if self.moving_up`, that doesn't make sense. 3. One assumption is that image coordinates indicate the top-left corner of the image, so you are checking not when the image touches the bottom, but when the top-left corner of it touches the bottom (although I don't know why would moving to the right work for you in this case).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i am not sure that here everyone  knows how to use  stackoverflow, you are not gods and you are  humans are making mistakes, if here someone thinks thay  that they dont made mistakes, i advice them  phsyciatric clinic. i have solved this problem  and  recommend you  everyone before do some actions, just ask the question does this  help you? and then  make it